# Getting an error, A call to PInvoke function unbalanced the stack

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, dll, dllimport

I wrote the following  `C++` code to create `win 32 Dynamic link library` :

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <some.h>

unsigned char  m_KSN[10];
unsigned char m_inintial_key[16];
unsigned char initial_key[16];

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) unsigned char* OnDecryption(LPCTSTR stringKSN, 
    LPCTSTR BDK){
        for( i=0;i<10;i++){
            m_KSN[i]=asctohex(stringKSN[2*i],stringKSN[2*i+1]); } 
        for( i=0;i<16;i++){
    m_inintial_key[i]=asctohex(BDK[2*i],BDK[2*i+1]);}
       GetInitalKey(m_KSN, m_inintial_key, initial_key);
       // GetInitialKey function written in `.lib` file. Data type of (Byte*a Byte*    b Byte* c) 
   return initial_key;
  }
```

Where as my `C#` code is:

```
static class DecryptionDll
{
  public String BDK = "0111111119ABCDEFFEDCBA9877777777";
  public String KSN = "62994900380000C00329";

  internal static class UnsafeNativeMethods
    {   
        const string _dllLocation = "finalTest.dll";
        [DllImport(_dllLocation)]
        public static extern byte OnDecryption(string ksn, String bdk);
     }
}
```

I put the `dll` file in my current directory, I got by the following command:

```
String path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.
GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
```

It shows me `my debug` folder is the current path. So i put the `dll` at there. I also got the to many post but not able to understand the `PInvoke` situation.
Please help me..

Please tell me what should i make changes in `c++` or `c#` code to call the methods written in `dll`.

I am extremely sorry for so many edits. It happens because of my slow connection

Comment: Possibly a `cdecl` vs. `stdcall` issue.

Comment: You need to ensure the calling convention matches on both sides.  Either add `__cdecl` in the C code and `CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl` in the p/invoke attribute, or else `__stdcall1` and `CallingConvention = CallingConvetion.StdCall`.

Comment: @BenVoigt Should i add the _cdecl after extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)?

Comment: @BenVoigt waiting for your reply :(

Comment: @Amit: I can't remember whether it goes there or after the return type.  The compiler will let you know if it's in the wrong place.

Comment: @BenVoigt I added it after extern and it works :)

Comment: @Amit: Did that fix the stack imbalance problem?  Your return type still doesn't match, but we need to address the stack problems first.

Comment: @BenVoigt Now i am bale to call the method written in DLL. But you are right that there is a problem in data type. Would it be possible for you correct in code because i don't have so much knowledge in c# and c++ or we can continue the chat

Answer (score 0):

Your C++ function is declared as returning a pointer to unsigned char data, but never returns anything. It's surprising that it compiles; given that declaration and the fact that there's no "return" statement, it seems like you should be getting an error from your C++ compiler.

I guess you mean to return the address of m_KSN, but where is that variable declared? From the naming, it looks like a member variable, but that function doesn't appear to be a member function.

**After your edit**, things still don't line up. There are lots of variables with m_ in the name, implying they're member variables. But there's no class present, and we don't see declarations for those variables.

In C#, you're declaring your function to return a single byte. You're returning a pointer to a byte from C++, which usually means you want to return a whole array of bytes. Should your C# declaration look more like this?

```
public static extern byte [] OnDecryption(string ksn, String bdk);
```

Your C++ code assumes the length of the passed strings and never tests them. You might be walking into a null string, or string that's shorter (or longer) than you think. Or a string that doesn't have valid hexadecimal characters.

Can you share with us why you specifically believe your "function unbalanced the stack" ? And what it is you mean your function to do?

I see **you've made some further edits**, which resolve the mystery behind the `m_` arrays you previously used -- though you have two declarations for the same `m_initial_key` variable. Is `m_ninitial_key` intentially different than `m_inintial_key` or is that a typo?

But the other concerns and questions still remain. I suppose a further question is about the `GetInitialKey()` function. It's not a well-known Windows function, so we can't guess what it does without its source code; maybe it expects parameters different than you're passing it and that's actually causing the problem.

**Since you want to return a pointer to the unsigned char array**, you can just do so using IntPtr. Once you get the IntPtr back in C#, using the `Marshal.Copy` function to copy data out of it into a `byte []` array.  That all looks like this:

```
    internal static class UnsafeNativeMethods
    {
        const string _dllLocation = "..\\..\\..\\FinalTest\\debug\\finalTest.dll";
        [DllImport(_dllLocation, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public static extern IntPtr OnDecryption(string ksn, String bdk );

        static public byte[] OnDecryptionWrapper(string ksn, string bdk)
        {
            byte[] data = new byte[10];
            IntPtr ptr = OnDecryption(ksn, bdk);

            Marshal.Copy(ptr, data, 0, 10);
            return data;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Oh Sorry , i didn't wrote the whole definitions . let me add to that code

Comment: Now it's completed. I am extremely sorry for this behaviour

Comment: GetInitialKey is function written in .lib file

Comment: I have added the data type of parameter passing in GetInitialKey functuons, but i think that it have no use to find this solution. May be assume that it OnDecryption method always return the unsigned char*

Comment: Is it your intention to return an array of bytes from your function? How long will that array be, and where is it located?

Comment: I want to return initial_key and it's value is unsigned char[16] to my c#